# Why does $\frac{1}{\gamma}(Kf,v)=\frac{1}{\gamma}(f,K^*v)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I am struggling to understand an inequality in a proof (pg. 325 Evans PDE) of the Second Existsnce Theorem for weak solutions (Theorem 4).

I’m fine with everything up until the statement 
$$\frac{1}{\gamma}(Kf,v)=\frac{1}{\gamma}(f,K^*v)$$
 where $v$ solves the ellpiptic problem 
$$\begin{cases}Lu=f &\text{in} \ \Omega \\ u=0 &\text{on} \ \partial\Omega\end{cases}.$$
and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the $L^2$ inner-product. 
The operator $Ku$ is defined as 
$$Ku=:\gamma L^{-1}_{\gamma}f,$$
 and 
$$h=:L^{-1}_{\gamma}f;$$
The operator $L_{\gamma}$ is defined as 
$$L_{\gamma}=:Lu+\gamma u.$$
 As it follows from Theorem 5, appendix §D.5, $$v-K^*v=0,$$
where $K^*$ is the adjoint of $K$.

Now, here is my attempt to explain it: expanding the equality out, we have
$$\frac{1}{\gamma}\int_{\Omega}Kf\cdot v \ dx =\frac{1}{\gamma}\int_{\Omega}K^*v\cdot f \ dx.$$
Thus, since $v=K^*v$, 
$$Kf\equiv f,$$
but for some reason, the preceding equality states 
$$\frac{1}{\gamma}(f,K^*v)= \frac{1}{\gamma}(f,v),$$
which suggests that in the original inequality, he did not follow this procedure since he could have done this in one step. Where have I gone wrong here. What is the explanation for this equality?

Comment: What is the definition of $K^*$?

Comment: @JohnMa Oh sorry, it is the adjoint of $K$.

Comment: How do you define an adjoint?

Comment: @JohnMa $L^*$ is defined as $L^*=:-\sum_{i,j=1}^n(a^{ij}v_{x_j})_{x_i}-\sum_{i=1}^n b^i v_{x_i}+\left(c-\sum_{i=1}^n b^i_{x_i}\right)v$ for $b_i\in C^1(\overline\Omega)$ and then you put this into the definition of $K$.